# display total on a textbox on buttonclick c#

Tags: c#

The total for each item can be displayed, but with a new click the total is replaced with a new item's total. But I want the total to be updated after each button click by adding the the new item's total to the previous total.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string item_code = textBox1.Text;
    int item;
    int.TryParse(item_code, out item);
    string quantity  = textBox2.Text;
    int qty;
    int.TryParse(quantity, out qty);
    int price = itemprice(item);
    int unit_total = price * qty;
    int total = 0;

    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 || dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count < 2)
    {
        dataGridView2.ColumnCount = 4;
        dataGridView2.Columns[0].Name = "Item";
        dataGridView2.Columns[1].Name = "Quantity";
        dataGridView2.Columns[2].Name = "Unit Price";
        dataGridView2.Columns[3].Name = "Unit Total";

        dataGridView2.Rows.Add(item, qty, price, unit_total);
        total = total + unit_total;
        textBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare `total` as a field (outside your `Button1_Click` method) because with every button click you are setting `total` to zero. And I also removed some unnecessary variables like `item_code` because you can directly parse `textBox1.Text` so there is no need to declare a string variable. Also there is no need for setting your `dataGridView2` column `Name` and `Count` with every button click, just put the code in your form constructor (in my case `Form1`). This part also doesn't make sense `dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 || dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count < 2` (maybe you wanted `&&` instead of `||`) so i replaced it with `dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1`.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataGridView2.ColumnCount = 4;
    dataGridView2.Columns[0].Name = "Item";
    dataGridView2.Columns[1].Name = "Quantity";
    dataGridView2.Columns[2].Name = "Unit Price";
    dataGridView2.Columns[3].Name = "Unit Total";
}

int total = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int item;
    int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out item);
    int qty;
    int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out qty);
    int price = itemprice(item);
    int unit_total = price * qty;

    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows.Add(item, qty, price, unit_total);
        total += unit_total;
        textBox5.Text = total.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use existing `text` and `convert` it to `integer` and add to `total`

```
var intText=0;
var trxtTotal = Int32.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out intText);
total = intText + total;
textBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare grandTotal variable outside the click event method and add grandTotal inside each click

```
private int grandTotal = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string item_code = textBox1.Text;
    int item;
    int.TryParse(item_code, out item);
    string quantity  = textBox2.Text;
    int qty;
    int.TryParse(quantity, out qty);
    int price = itemprice(item);
    int unit_total = price * qty;
    int total = 0;

    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 || dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count < 2)

    {


            dataGridView2.ColumnCount = 4;
            dataGridView2.Columns[0].Name = "Item";
            dataGridView2.Columns[1].Name = "Quantity";
            dataGridView2.Columns[2].Name = "Unit Price";
            dataGridView2.Columns[3].Name = "Unit Total";

            dataGridView2.Rows.Add(item, qty, price, unit_total);
            grandTotal =grandTotal + unit_total;
            textBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(grandTotal );


    }



}
```